# Adding license to new files when using Eclipse and the Copyright wizard plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, copyright-display

I've just installed this [Copyright wizard plugin](http://www.wdev91.com/?p=cpw) for managing copyright disclaimers in my Eclipse projects. I discovered it thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204676/how-to-manage-license-banners-in-source-files-of-eclipse-plug-in-projects).

I set it up and all works fine:

1. I created my own copyright header
2. I used the wizard to apply it to all files of an existing project

Now I have the following problem:

When I create a new file inside the project, the copyright isn't added by default. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're looking for Eclipse's [`Code Templates`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/codestyle/ref-preferences-code-templates.htm) feature. In the version of Eclipse I have handy, it's found through Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates.

I have a feeling that you will be most interested in either the `New Java files` (found under Code) or `Files` (found under Comments) template.

There is corresponding functionality for XML files under Preferences -> XML -> XML Files -> Editor -> Templates (look at the `xml declaration` template), and for Ant files under Preferences -> Ant -> Editor -> Templates (`Buildfile template`). I am willing to bet that there are similar templates for pretty much every other language Eclipse can be used with.

Comment: No. It's what I'm looking for. I know that, but accordingly to the post I linked the Copyright wizard plugin is built exactly for manage copyright headers. It's more flexible than a Code Template. I would like to understand how to configure it in order to automatically add the header using that plugin.